# :footnotes extension won't work in Redcarpet Ruby gem

Tags: markdown, redcarpet

I must be missing something very obvious -- I can't get footnotes to work with redcarpet. I have version 3.0.0:

```
> gem list redcarpet
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

redcarpet (3.0.0)
```

I am trying code from the [test code on the Github repo](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet/blob/59bfded76b99700c0c34a2a0fda29cffc46ec242/test/html_render_test.rb) that has footnotes and it won't convert the Markdown to HTML that contains the footnote. I reduced the code down to just the footnotes function and [put it on Gist](https://gist.github.com/siruguri/6603806).

The output is simply as follows:

```
<p>This is a footnote.[^1]</p>
<p>[^1]: It provides additional information.</p>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this problem as well. It looks like the Rubygem needs to be updated past version `3.0.0` in order for footnotes to work. There are changes in the `master` branch which aren't available on Rubygems.

To fix your issue for the time being, source the gem from the Redcarpet Github repo:

`gem 'redcarpet', github: 'vmg/redcarpet', branch: 'master'`

Then run `bundle install`. Footnotes should now work.

I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet/issues/322) on the Redcarpet repo to try to get someone to update the Rubygem with the latest changes. I'll post back here if/when that's done.

Comment: To be clear, I was looking to use the gem in a stand-along Ruby app, so I did the equivalent of the above via `gem build` and `gem install` (as per http://rubyguide.blogspot.com/2012/02/installing-gem-fork-from-github-source.html) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the `:footnotes` extension is only on master ; we haven't yet released a version which ships with this feature. This will be in 3.1.0 (since we are using [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/)) that we are about to release (we have still some adjustments to do). You can safely depend on the master branch of the repository ; we are always ensuring that our test suite is green on Travis!

Thank you, have a nice day!